# How to localize popup of firefox extension using firefox sdk 1.17?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing firefox extension using firefox SDK 1.17.
In this I am using (popup) panel (require("sdk/panel").Panel).
I want to localize the strings of popup.
Please let me know if any solution.

Answer (score 2):

The SDK supports localization, [please see the docs for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/l10n).

Comment: Thanks for replay.. But I want do localization in panel

Comment: The "Using Localized Strings in HTML" part is about the localization in a panel.

Comment: What if you want to populate the localized string during runtime. Then you cannot use the data-l10n-id attribute